# T-Test on Residuals or Z-standardized Variables?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, residuals

I have data from 2 tissues, from the same persons.
However, in the variable I am interested in (say "X"), there are shifts in the mean values for the two tissues that are related to the computation of X. To get rid of these shifts, I z-standardized this variable (per tissue, name it "ZX").
Further, I wanted to control the variable for some covariates, I did this by regression and taking the residuals ("residX").
So I have a variable ZX and a variable residX.
Now I want to know for both these variables, if they are significantly different between the tissues.

Can I test this by performing a paired t-test on the variables? To say it general, can we perform paired t-tests on z-standardized or residual variables? I am so unsure/confused because we bring them to mean 0 and in t-tests we do test the means...

Thanks for help!